# Is there a ln symlink command in Windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does window have the ln -s or equivalent?](https://superuser.com/questions/182553/does-window-have-the-ln-s-or-equivalent)

Is there an equivalent `ln` command to create symlinks in Windows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. Among others, there is `mklink`: [**Using Symlinks in Windows Vista**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/)

A good blog article on the subject, if you're interested in the history, is [**here**](http://bluedragon.blog-city.com/symbolic_links_on_windows_why_and_how.htm).

There's exhaustive documentation (from the API perspective) on Symbolic Links and Windows at MSDN: [**Symbolic Links**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365680%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that mklink is not available in PowerShell. It is a built-in command available only in cmd.exe.  The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) has a New-SymLink cmdlet in it if you need this support in PowerShell.

Comment: You could also call `cmd /c mklink ...` which might be a little less intrusive than installing PSCX :-).