# Does Windows have the ln -s or equivalent?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I need to link a file to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

How can I do that with Windows ? Is there a soft link such as `ln -s` or equivalent in Windows ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are looking for the command "mklink" (cmd) or the "New-Item" command (powershell).

- cmd:

Documentation and examples in [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) or [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html).

Example taken from the link:

```
// To create a symbolic link named MyDocs from the root directory to the \Users\User1\Documents directory, type:
mklink /d \MyDocs \Users\User1\Documents
```

- powershell:

Documentation and examples in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.3). Search the page for symbolic link.

Example from the link:

```
$link = New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path .\link -Target\Notice.txt 
$link | Select-Object LinkType, Target

LinkType     Target
--------     ------
SymbolicLink {.\Notice.txt}
```

Comment: Please note that you need Administrator privileges to create symbolic links.

Answer (score 20):

There may be other ways, but the one I'm familiar with is mklink:

```
C:\>mklink 
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```

Answer (score 9):

## Powershell

As long as Microsoft advices to use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) as a command interpreter since more than 5 years ago and `cmd.exe` is becoming a legacy application this question lacks an answer in Powershell:

```
New-Item -path ~\Desktop\hosts -itemType SymbolicLink -target c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

This works as of Powershell v5.0

Answer (score 3):

There are [junctions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) but I don't know if this will do exactly what you need.

edit - oops sorry, junction only applies to directories not files

Answer (score 2):

As @inf says, [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx) is the solution for Vista and above.

For 2000/XP, you can use [fsutil hardlink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788097%28WS.10%29.aspx). Note that, unlike mklink, hardlink doesn't work across drives.

Comment: Also worthy of note is that some people may not be aware, but hardlinks *become the file*. In other words it's possible to delete the original and the link still works (and this is why it can't work across drives).

Comment: According to the link you provided, [fsutil hardlink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788097%28WS.10%29.aspx), `fsutil hardlink` is only for Vista and above. Is there an older version available for Windows 2000 and XP?

Comment: Indeed it is available for XP, as described in the [Windows XP fsutil hardlink](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil_hardlink.mspx?mfr=true) docs. I can't testify to its functionality in Windows 2000, but it does work in Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

[Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) can create symbolic link (among other things).
Nice context menu integration.
Available for the most recent windows versions and frequently updated.

Answer (score -2):

open the Terminal/CMD
under the android/sdk/tools,type

Terminal** ln -s emulator64-x86 emulator-x86**
CMD**mklink emulator64-x86 emulator-x86**

this will get created like..

**symbolic link created for emulator64-x86 <<===>> emulator-x86**