# Reflecting changes to a file in a different location

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, file-management

I have five different folders which share a number of common data files between them. That is to say that the same data file may be present in more than one of the above mentioned folders. Each of these folders also contain some other code files, specific to the folders, which reference the data files in their own folder. The data files are subject to change from time to time.

Now, I need the code to work on the data files when I copy only that folder in which the code resides, so *the data has to be in the same folder as the code* and has to referenced with a relative path as well.

My question is, would there happen to be some way in which, when I make edits to a data file and save it, the changes automatically get reflected in the corresponding data files in other folders as well?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

**P.S.:** Keeping the data files in a common folder and copying that as well is not a viable option for me.

**Note:** I am working on a Windows 7 system. OS specific solutions would of course be helpful but it would be great if the solution were to be OS independent.

Comment: I've never had much luck with symbolic links in Windows, but maybe have a look at this and see if it does what you need: http://superuser.com/questions/182553/does-window-have-the-ln-s-or-equivalent