# Why is a Windows symlink different from that in Unix?

Tags: windows, unix, symbolic-link

I've been searching on the web about this. Everything I can find states that Windows `mklink` behaves like Unix `ln -s` ([example in this site](https://superuser.com/questions/182553/does-windows-have-the-ln-s-or-equivalent)).

However, I want to set JDK up so I can access it as just `javac` and `java` from anywhere. I chose to add just those two in a separate folder to the Path environment variable instead of the whole `bin` folder because there's a lot of other stuff in there (unrelated: does it matter?).

I did this successfully in the past in a Debian box through `ln -s`, so apparenly it should work just fine with `mklink`, but what happens instead is I get a "can't find DLL" error as though I had simply made a copy of the executables.

So, question is: **why do these two commands behave differently?** (even though they're said not to)

Comment: They act differently because they are not identical.  There an on topic question here?  None of the linked questions answers claim the command works similarly or identically to the Linux command.  Likewise the system variable also works differently on Linux

Comment: Oh, well. I may have made too many assumptions in the process.

Comment: Your question about `javac` would require you to change your `PATH` variable and not use a symlink.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the executable is started from the symlink with as its current
directory the one where the symlink resides, rather than the one where the
executable resides, so the DLLs in the executable's directory are not found.

I agree that according to the definition of the search algorithm as given by
Microsoft, the DLLs should have been found.
This is most probably a deficiency in the DLL-search algorithm of Windows
and there is nothing you can do about it.

A workaround would be to use another mechanism than symlink,
storing in the Path folder a `.bat` file instead of a symlink.
The file would look something like:

```
cd \path\to\exe-folder
exe-file
```