# Windows: How to make shortcuts act like folders in explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Currently, I have two folders on my desktop, Real Folder 1 and Real Folder 2. I also have a shortcut to "Real Folder 3" on desktop.When I launch a program, the following browsing window comes up:

[image: program window]

The shortcut to Real Folder 3 does not show up in this standard windows control. Is there any way to tweak the shortcut to make it behave like a normal folder so it will show up in this browse for folder dialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, you want to look up making a *symlink* using the `mklink` utility to create a directory link from `Desktop\Real Folder 3` to wherever `Real Folder 3` is located. Symbolic links (symlinks) are easiest imagined as virtual folders or files.

There are other questions on [SU] which detail how to create and manage symlinks:

[Is there a ln symlink command in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/111576/is-there-a-ln-symlink-command-in-windows-7)