# Restructure The C:\ Directory Without Affecting Programs

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, filesystems, file-management, redirection

**I'm want to do some tweaking to my PC's file hierarchy, but just moving folders and files around disables programs that depend on certain files to be in certain hard-coded addresses.**

**One solution** that I'm hoping for is a Background Windows Service that'd keep track of file and folder movements. Then, whenever a program besides a file manager would try to access a moved file or folder, the service would re-direct it to the correct location. Manual entering of redirects is also a must.

**How might I go about doing this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a ln symlink command in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/111576/is-there-a-ln-symlink-command-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** This works natively on Windows 7 or Vista  only (Not XP or earlier - the command doesn't exist)

If, say, you wanted to move a program to a different harddrive, you could use the mklink command to make a **directory symbolic link**

For example, lets say i have Steam installed to `C:\Program Files\Steam`

but, thanks to the recent steam sales, my OS harddrive is starting to fill up. I have another harddrive with plenty of space, so I shutdown steam, cut the directory to the new harddrive (at `X:\Steam`) and in a command prompt window, i type

```
cd "C:\Program Files"
mklink /D "Steam" "X:\Steam"
```

(`/D` makes a directory symbolic link, instead of the default file symbolic link)

Now, if you browse to Program Files using explorer, there will be a shortcut-looking folder (it'll have the little arrow on the icon) and if you open it, the path in the explorer window will still say `C:\Program Files\Steam`.

So windows is happy, as far as it's concerned steam is still at Program files, and I'm happy, because my OS drive now has a bit more space.

I think you can even set the link to be hidden if you don't want to see it in Program Files, but i haven't tried because i'm not that worried about it.

[mklink reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, when you open the command prompt window, run it as administrator if you're editing Program Files (Right-Click -> Run as Administrator) otherwise you might not have permission to create a file in Program Files.

Comment: Note, i realise it's not exactly what you asked for, but this is how I move around 'immovable' directories

Comment: Thanks for the information, it'll really help if I end up having to make the software myself!

Comment: you could throw this in a WinForms app pretty quickly I reckon. There's probably a few floating around the web as well

Comment: And here we go. first Google result: http://code.google.com/p/symlinker/

Comment: Symbolic links are not available before Windows Vista (except probably some server version, I don't know about those). If you're on XP or older you may be able to user junctions instead.

Comment: @Erik - OP tagged windows 7 so I was addressing that, but thanks i've added that to the answer